# How to access the Safehouse location in SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud

I would like to access the SafeHouse location through FTP.

I am aware that file transfer in automation studio is one way to do it.

I was wondering if I can login to a FTP location and view the extracts as well.

Comment: The whole point of the safehouse is to prevent access to files extracted -- especially decrypted ones.

Answer (score 7):

I don't think this is possible.

As far as I know, the safe house is not accessible except via an File Transfer automation.  You *can* log in to an SFTP location but you have to use the File Transfer automation to move the data to that SFTP site (either hosted by SF or an external one).

Answer (score 0):

You can not.

The function of the safehouse is for added security for unencrypted files and unprotected data. If you had access to it via FTP, it would bypass the purpose of this security measure.

It's a bit of a hassle, but you must know what you are extracting to the safehouse in order to specifically move it to the SFTP or access it in a secure manner.